# Request id doesn't find whit findbyid method as a requestparam

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, repository

I'm doing a service that is connected to an MySQL database, and I have a problem with a method that I'm requesting a parameter. But it seems that it doesn't read.

I mean, in the print that I make, it returns the parameter. But in findbyId method doesn't find the file requested.

MainController method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/festivales")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private FestivalRepository festivalRepository;

@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

//http://localhost:8080/festivales/all-festivales
@GetMapping(path="/all-festivales")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Festival> getAllFestivales() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return festivalRepository.findAll();
}

//Doesn't work
    @GetMapping("/all-festivales/{id}")
    public Festival getFestival(@PathVariable int id) throws Exception {
        Optional<Festival> student = festivalRepository.findById(id);

        if (!student.isPresent())
            throw new Exception("id-" + id);

        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(student.get());
        System.out.println(student.get().toString());


        return student.get();
    }
```

The other methods that can help to know what I'm trying to do:

The class Festival:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Festival {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String descripcion;
    private String genero;
    private double precio;
    private int dias;
    private String fecha_ini;
    private String fecha_fin;

    public Festival() {}

    public Festival(int id, String name, String descripcion, String genero, double precio, int dias, String fecha_ini, String fecha_fin) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.dias = dias;
        this.fecha_ini = fecha_ini;
        this.fecha_fin = fecha_fin;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getDias() {
        return dias;
    }

    public void setDias(int dias) {
        this.dias = dias;
    }

    public String getFecha_ini() {
        return fecha_ini;
    }

    public void setFecha_ini(String fecha_ini) {
        this.fecha_ini = fecha_ini;
    }

    public String getFecha_fin() {
        return fecha_fin;
    }

    public void setFecha_fin(String fecha_fin) {
        this.fecha_fin = fecha_fin;
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.pruebas.festivalapp.model.Festival;

//This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
//CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface FestivalRepository extends CrudRepository<Festival, Integer> {

}
```

Also, say that the service that I'm trying to do it doesn't crash and when I do the maven install or I run the application, all goes Ok.

This is MySQL data that I put in the localhost where to attack it:

The json when I select to get all the festivals:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Viñarock",
    "descripcion": "Festival de rock rap y mestizaje",
    "genero": "rock",
    "precio": 50.0,
    "dias": 3,
    "fecha_ini": "10-05-2019",
    "fecha_fin": "12-05-2019"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Resurrection Fest",
    "descripcion": "Festival de rock, metal, hardcore..",
    "genero": "rock",
    "precio": 80.0,
    "dias": 3,
    "fecha_ini": "10-07-2019",
    "fecha_fin": "12-07-2019"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "MareaRock Fest",
    "descripcion": "Festival de punk rock",
    "genero": "punk",
    "precio": 15.0,
    "dias": 1,
    "fecha_ini": "10-04-2019",
    "fecha_fin": "12-04-2019"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Festardor",
    "descripcion": "Festival de punk y rap",
    "genero": "otros",
    "precio": 20.0,
    "dias": 2,
    "fecha_ini": "10-09-2019",
    "fecha_fin": "12-09-2019"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Festival de les arts",
    "descripcion": "Festival indie",
    "genero": "otros",
    "precio": 40.0,
    "dias": 2,
    "fecha_ini": "10-06-2019",
    "fecha_fin": "12-06-2019"
  }
]
```

Could anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You provided tow ending points with the same path "all-festivales/{id} i don't know how application even run as this lead to ambiguity you must provide unique path within same request method so delete first one and use second with  @PathVariable should work

Comment: Hi Samir, is a mistake from the copy.. sorry

Comment: never mind, and when you call http://localhost:8080/festivales/all-festivales works fine ?

Comment: Yes, as you see, the last code is a json code that is what it return me when i make that call